# Can I return document data after a FTS match?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Suppose I have this data:

```
{
   "test": "Testing1234" 
   "false": "Falsify"
}
```

And then using curl, I write this query:

```
{"explain": true, "fields": [ "*" ], "highlight": {}, "query": { "query": "Testing"}}
```

I get a response from couchbase. This includes the document id, as well as a `locations` object that returns details about where my query matched text in the document, including the parent object. All useful information.

However, I do not receive any additional context. For instance, say I have 100 documents with `"test": "TestingXXXX"` where XXXX is a random string. My search will not provide me with XXXX. Nor does it provide me any way to read additional fields in the same object (for instance, if I wanted to fetch the "false" property). I will simply get 100 different document IDs to query. Thus, it is technically enough information to obtain all the needed information, however it results in me making 100 different requests based on parsed info from the original response.

Is there any way to return context with FTS matches when using the REST API, without simply querying every document that is matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's not an issue with the query. The fields were not being indexed. To fix, I changed the index setting "Store Dynamic Fields" to "True". That said the highlighting did return a lot of extra details and I'm sure it also increases the query times quite a bit. The couchbase documentation seemed to imply it is only used for debugging. Thus, I would like to leave this open in case anyone has further suggestions.

Comment: Try adding `includeLocations:true` to the query. That should get you information about the actual hit locations. Unfortunately I can't test it right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the complete objects by issuing the FTS query from within N1QL using the CURL() function, and then joining that up with the objects themselves.

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/curl.html

Your query would have roughly this form:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable
USE KEYS CURL(ftsURL, ftsQuery, ...)
```

You'll need to wrap the CURL function in some transformation functions to turn the FTS result into an array of ids.

I realize this is quite schematic, since I don't have a full example handy. But work up through these steps:

1. Issue the FTS query through CURL() in N1QL.
2. Transform the FTS results into an array of ids.
3. Embed the request for the array of ids into a SELECT query using USE KEYS.

Comment: I see - I will make sure to give this a try and report back. Seems like a good solution to me.